# parent must exist when saving nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models `slide` and `cards`.

```
class Slide < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cards,-> { order(:position) },dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards,reject_if: proc { |attr| attr['title'].blank?}
end
```

and in `SlideController`

```
  def create
    @slide = Slide.new(get_params)
    @slide.save
  end
```

When I try to save slide with cards , I get the error

> @messages={:"cards.slide"=>["must exist"]}, @details={:"cards.slide"=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>

if i remove `-> { order(:position) }` from `has_many` then everything works fine. Slide is created first when nested attributes are submitted if i am correct, whats going on ?

Comment: the error message looks incomplete

Comment: `order` is used only when reading the association, shouldn't have anything to do with when writing to it

Comment: Please create "default_scope" for order "position" then everything will be ok .

Comment: @emaillenin i have added the complete error message. i do understand order shouldnt affect but removing it fixes the problem so I am confused

Comment: @user3678149 that would solve the issue but i do not want a default scope on all calls so i  would prefer scope with association

Comment: Then "optional: true" in Card model.
belongs_to :slide , optional: true

Comment: But it is not optional. The data is already present